# Du tells me it can't find the current directory?

Tags: aix, du

I'm on AIX, and in some directories I can't use the `du` command.  I get the follow error message:

> du: 0653-175 Cannot find the current directory.

Obviously the current directory exists, and I have permissions to it.  I can list the directory and create  files in it, both before and after I ran `du`.  What could possibly be wrong here?

The `du` command works just fine in my home directory.

A quick google search turns up a bunch of forum posts of the same problem, but no clear answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the permissions of the directory under the filesystem mount?  Unmount the filesystem and check the permissions of the directory underneath, it's probably not `root:system` and 755.  Your user ID probably doesn't have access to that directory and *some* AIX commands fail as a result.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably because of ACL implemented on that directory. You may want to change to that filesyste,/directory owner and then try du.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of privilege. Run your command as **super user** then it will show results.

```
oracle@dbprod:/grid/base/tfa/repository/suptools/vt1prod/oswbb/oracle/archive:> du -sm .
du: 0653-175 Cannot find the current directory.

oracle@dbprod:/grid/base/tfa/repository/suptools/vt1prod/oswbb/oracle/archive:> sudo du -sm .
821.88  .
```